# A nice function to escape $_POST // what do you think about it

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using $_POST and aware about mysql exploit, I decided to use this function on the top of my page, therefore all POST will be safe:
Can you tell me if I miss something and this function will really do the job as I think it will?

```
function clean_post(){
    if ( $_POST){
            foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
            $_POST[$k]=stripslashes($v);
            $_POST[$k]=mysql_real_escape_string($v);
            $_POST[$k]=preg_replace('/<.*>/', "", "$v");
        }
  }

  if ( $_COOKIE){
            foreach ($_COOKIE as $k => $v) {
            $_COOKIE[$k]=stripslashes($v);
            $_COOKIE[$k]=mysql_real_escape_string($v);
            $_COOKIE[$k]=preg_replace('/<.*>/', "", "$v");
        }
  }
}
```

It will also remove all html tag, a safest option to output the result might be to use:

```
<pre>
  $foo 
</pre>
```

Cheers!

Cheers!

Comment: What would be the use of this? Why would anyone need something like this? I know I don't. For mysql, I use PDO with prepared statements, so I don't need to escape anyting from post. For other things I use php's built-in filter_var() with various options.

Comment: Its good to see you are thinking about security, Great keep it up!. but... mysql_real_escape_string requires an active database connection. so your function will error out if you use it before connecting to mysql. it may also cause issues if you have multiple connections to different databases that use different collations. before you stripslashes you should always check to see that php added slashes using `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`. What if you inadvertently call the function twice?

Comment: Congratulations, you have found a way to turn your input into garbage! :o)

Answer (score 10):

I think it's a bad idea to do this. It will corrupt the data your users enter even before it hits the database. This approach will also encourage you to use lazy coding where you consistently don't escape data because you believe that all your data is already "clean". This will come back to bite you one day when you do need to output some unsafe characters and you either forget to escape them or you aren't really sure which function you need to call so you just try something and hope that it works.

To do it properly you should ensure that [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is disabled and only escape data when necessary, using precisely the correct escaping method - no more, no less.

Comment: I can't understand this part : *you don't escape anything* . He is escaping characters ? Can you explain it? Thnaks.

Comment: @Eray Alakese: My point is that he most likely will use this cleaning function *instead* of escaping data correctly. I think this is a dangerous habit to get into.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with it.

First you apply functions on types that doesn't need them, your integers for example needs only a (int) cast to be secure.

Second you do not secure lenght, when you're requesting a '12 chars string' it would be a good idea to ensure you've got only 12 chars, and not 2048. Limiting size is really something your attackers will not like.

Third in your foreach loop you have a $v variable, you assign 3 times a function on $v to $_POST[$k]. So the 1st two assignements are lost when the 3rd occurs...

Then all the things previous people said are right :-)

The rule is apply the filter at the right moment for the right output. HTML output need an html filter (htmlspecialchars), but the database doesn't need it, it need a database escaping. Let's say you want to extract data from your database to build a CSV or a PDF, HTML escaping will make you life harder. You'll need CSV escaping at this time, or PDF escaping.

Finally it is effectively hard to remember if you are manipulating a data which is already well escaped for your output. And I recommend you an excellent read on Joel on Software about [Apps Hungarian](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). The text is quite long, but very good, and the web escaping sequence is used as an example on why Apps Hungarian is good (even if System Hungarain is bad).

Comment: you assign 3 times a function on $v to $_POST[$k]. How can I had missed that!

Comment: So you're quite exposed on SQl injections now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is my first answer for any question asked on web so please review it.

Put this code in top of your script and no need to assign these posted values to any variables for doing the same job of making the input data safe for database. Just use $_POST values as it is in your query statements.

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {                  
      if(!is_array($_POST[$k]) ) {       //checks for a checkbox array & so if present do not escape it to protect data from being corrupted.
          if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) {      
                $v = stripslashes($v); 
            }               

            $v = preg_replace('/<.*>/', "", "$v");           //replaces html chars
            $_POST[$k]= mysql_real_escape_string(trim($v));

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with stripslashes I'd use [`get_magic_quotes_gpc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php):

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_POST[$k]=stripslashes($v);
}
```

Otherwise you'll over-strip.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget $_GET[]

```
if ($_POST OR $_GET)
```

Also you can add **strip_tags()**

Comment: Actually, just use $_REQUEST (both $_POST and $_GET) and call it a day

Comment: @editor using request is ambiguous and definitely not a good idea.  Also, changing request will not change what is in get or post, its not by reference.

Comment: Good points, although when reading vars from a client that would seem acceptable. Can you explain what you mean by ambiguous? Do you mean when reading the code or something else? It saves me a lot of code when I want to support both GET and POST for an API method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your function is correct or not, but the principle is certainly incorrect.  You want to escape only where you need to, i.e. just before you pass things into MySQL (in fact you don't even want to do that, ideally; use bound parameters).

There are plenty of situations where you might want the raw data as passed in over the HTTP request.  With your approach, there's no ability to do so.

Comment: use bound parameters : Never heard about that can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

In general, I don't think it's that good of an idea.

1. Not all post data necessarily goes into MySQL, so there is no need to escape it if it doesn't. That said, using something like PDO and prepared statements is a better way, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.
2. The regular expression could destroy a lot of potentially valid text. You should worry about things like HTML when outputting, not inputting. Furthermore, use a function like `strip_tags` or `htmlspecilchars` to handle this.
3. `stripslashes` is only necessary if magic quotes are enabled (which they shouldn't be, but always is possible)